# My loop is not ending properly

Tags: java, loops

```
//deposit case 
case "deposit":
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"We accept the following dollar bills:\n1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100"
        + "\nPlease insert the bill on the console."
        + "\nEnter any other number to stop depositing."
        ,"Insert Bill",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    System.out.println("Insert bills here.");

    int deposit = keyboard.nextInt();

    int total = 0; 

    while (deposit==1||deposit==5||deposit==10||deposit==20||deposit==50||deposit==100)
    {

        total += deposit;
        //System.out.println(deposit);
        deposit = keyboard.nextInt();
        //System.out.println(deposit);
        keyboard.close();

       // if (deposit!=1||deposit!=5||deposit!=10||deposit!=20||deposit!=50||deposit!=100)
       // {
         //   break;
       // }

    }


    acc.deposit(total);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You deposited "+total+" dollars."
                                    +"\nThe current balance is: $"+acc.showBalance()
                                    ,"Deposit into Account" ,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    break;

//withdraw case    
case "withdraw":

    int money = 0;
    String moneyString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter amount you want to withdraw"
                                                    ,"Withdraw from Account",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    if (moneyString == null||moneyString.length()==0)
    {
        money = 0;
    }
    else {
        money = Integer.parseInt(moneyString);
    }

    acc.withdraw(money);

    break;
```

Comment: Don't `close()` your `keyboard` inside the loop...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you close out your scanner `keyboard` after you use it the first time in the loop and never open it again. Try to close your scanner just before closing the program or after all deposits have been completed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the issue. I'm on a Mac and my JOptionPane windows were popping up behind my editor. Sorry, this post is useless.